# で in 前回で in this sentence

Tags: particle-で

> 安定のシリーズ四作目。**前回で**微妙だった部分をすぐに修正してきたのはさすが

about a the 4th game of a series

feels very unintuitive to me, compared to `前回の微妙だった部分` for instance

Comment: Me too, but can you supply the context?

Comment: 安定のシリーズ四作目。 前回で微妙だった部分をすぐに修正してきたのはさすが it is the first line of a review, so there is no context

Comment: That's rather an important context clarifying what role 前回で plays in your phrase (and that it isn't a complete sentence).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This で represents a relatively minor usage, which can be translated "at the point/stage", "at the time when", or "when in/at" (often with implicit contrast to some other points).

> 前回**の**微妙だった部分 *unimpressive features **of/in** the previous (game)*
> 前回**で**微妙だった部分 *unimpressive features (existed) **at the point of** the previous (game)*

Of course, in this case, the meaning does not change much as to what is referred, but:

> × 前回**の**修正されたバグが…
> ○ 前回**で**修正されたバグが… *Bugs fixed in (the time of) the last release...*
> ≒ 前回修正されたバグが…
> ……復活した。 ...*has occurred again.*
>
> ○ 前回**の**あらすじ *the last episode's digest* (= in the last episode...)
> × 前回**での**あらすじ
> cf. 前回**までの**あらすじ *the digest as of the last episode* (= previously on...)

So the overall translation would be like:

> The down-to-earth fourth title of the series (franchise). What's admirable about them is their quickness in reworking of unimpressive features seen in the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

I take this で as functioning like the English "about" or "with" and being more or less synonymous with (more formal) "において". This usage is pretty common, I think. Thus we find ample examples like this on the web such as:

> "私達の対応**で**悪いところ・残念なところを教えてください。" "Please tell us about bad points and/or disappointing points **about/with** our response/treatment."
>
> "英会話スクール**で**不満な点は？" "(What are) things you find dissatisfying **about/with** English conversation schools?"
>
> "乃木坂46の歌詞**で**分からない所。" "A part/parts I don't understand **about/with** the lyrics of 乃木坂46."

So "前回**で**微妙だった部分" I'd translate to something like

> "parts/points that were "meh" **about/with** the previous installment".

And of course the version with a genitive "の" works too. (""meh" parts **of** the previous installment")